# Many to Many self Join with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Consider this `Poco`:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want to implement a follow technique where a user may follow other users so basically its self Many to Many relationship

problem is i don't know how exactly i can achieve this in `Entity Framework` `Code-First` ?

I thought  of  a  linker Table :

```
    public class UserFollow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Follower { get; set; }
    public int Following { get; set; }
    public DateTime FollowDate { get; set; }
}
```

i want to be able to get All Followers and Following from every User Object?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple using EF code-first as you only need the User POCO:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> FollowedUsers { get; set; }
}
```

The collection means that a `User` is related to other users.

PS: I noted you added a timestamp in your solution example. To achieve that you should still add the collection changing the generic type to whatever suits your needs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How is this written in the configuration file?