# How can I make a Many to many relation on same table (many to many Join To Self)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-design, relational-database

I have a problem in my project. 
In one database relations have a join to self with many to many.

What any of people solve this problem in Entity FrameWork?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any many-to-many relationship should create a new table to represent the pairings.

Example: say you have a table `People`, and you want to show who gave birthday gifts.  A person can give gifts to many friends, and a person may receive gifts from many other people.

```
CREATE TABLE People (person_id INT PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE GiftGiving (
  from_person_id INT,
  to_person_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (from_person_id, to_person_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (from_person_id) REFERENCES People(person_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (to_person_id)   REFERENCES People(person_id)
);
```

Re your comment:

For EF implementations, see these related questions:

- [Many to Many self Join with Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636256/many-to-many-self-join-with-entity-framework-code-first)
- [Entity Framework many-to-many self-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640000/entity-framework-many-to-many-self-reference)
- [Self-referencing many-to-many recursive relationship code first Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125052/self-referencing-many-to-many-recursive-relationship-code-first-entity-framework)

Comment: Hi Bill.  New to SQL here.  Is it the commonly held recommended style to Uppercase Table Names? Is there a style guide you would recommend? Also I noticed, in a sense you put the `from_person_id` twice as `from_person_id INT` and `FOREIGN KEY (from_person_id) REFERENCES People(person_id),` why is that? Could you have just had the `FOREIGN KEY (from_person_id) REFERENCES People(person_id),`? Would there be down sides to that?

Comment: The column definition and the foreign key are separate. You can't make a foreign key constraint unless you first define the column. For example, there is no place in a foreign key constraint to define the column's data type or other column options. Some databases support a shorthand , but MySQL does not support it (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727924/major-bug-in-mysql-8-x-foreign-keys/63728082#63728082).

Comment: As for style guide, there's no universal style guide for SQL. What is more important is that you choose what works for you in a given project, then you follow it consistently in your project. This is the same guidance as for most programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

I simply put an ICollection to itself. Let EF handle the db layer.
public class Person{
public virtual ICollection OtherPersons {get;set;}
}